# Why java unknown: import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;?

Tags: java, import, base64

I want do program like here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hP2x1fwYP6c&feature=youtu.be&t=359
and I would like to *import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;* but [java unknown apache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYOp9.png)
Or do I have to upload a library? 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the Apache Commons Codec library to your project. You either need to download the *.jar file and add it to the project folder and project configuration or you let your build processor automatically download it.

See https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9
Latest is version 1.15

This website provides a download link for the *.jar file as well as configuration settings for different build processors (Maven, Gradle, ...)

Answer (score 0):

*org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64* is not part of the default java language, it is part of a library.

To use it you have to put said library on the classpath.

If you use a build and dependency management tool like maven you can add it as dependency in the pom.xml file.